# Image.FromStream throws Parameter is not valid error only on linux

Tags: c#, linux, image, asp.net-core, file-upload

I have some Unit Tests made in .net core that checks if the file which is uploaded from angular frontend is actually resized on the backend.

I have a service that is used in the tests, containing following method :

```
public byte[] ResizeImage(IFormFile formFile)
    {
        Image imgFromStream;
        using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formFile.CopyTo(memStream);
            memStream.Position = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("$$$$$$$ LENGTH  :" + memStream.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("$$$$$$$ CAN READ :" + memStream.CanRead);
          

   
 ->>>>>           imgFromStream = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memStream, false,false);

            Image thumbnail = imgFromStream.GetThumbnailImage(280, 90, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

            var imageByteArray = new byte[0];

            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thumbnail.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                imageByteArray = mStream.ToArray();
            }
            imgFromStream.Dispose();
            thumbnail.Dispose();
            return imageByteArray;
        }

    }
```

The issue is that only on Linux machine, the tests are failing from the line with (---->>>).
I've tried with ImageConverter, linux has a bad opinion for that too and it is still not working.
I'm out of ideas.

```
StackTrace :   at System.Drawing.Image.InitializeFromStream(Stream stream)
at System.Drawing.Image.LoadFromStream(Stream stream, Boolean keepAlive)
at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
```

The method that creates the Image for tests :

```
 public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        int size = (int)Math.Sqrt(byteArrayIn.Length);

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(size, size, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        try
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < bitmapData.Height; ++rowIndex)
                Marshal.Copy(byteArrayIn, rowIndex * bitmap.Width, bitmapData.Scan0 + rowIndex * bitmapData.Stride, bitmap.Width);
        }
        finally
        {
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

And the `byteArrayIn` parameter is generated :

```
     private byte[] GenerateImageByteArray(int sizeInMb)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();


        Byte[] b = new Byte[sizeInMb * 1024 * 1024]; // convert mb to byte
        rnd.NextBytes(b);

        //This conversion is needed because the GetThumbnail method from the Service will throw an error
        //A random generated byte array can not be converted into a thumbnail
        //Only if it's from an image
        var image = ByteArrayToImage(b);
        var imageByteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            imageByteArray=mStream.ToArray();
        }

        return imageByteArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `System.Drawing.Common` on linux you need to install GDI+ support libraries:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev 
sudo apt install libgdiplus
```

Comment: Now i'm getting Out of memory.
 at System.Drawing.Image.InitializeFromStream(Stream stream)

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46405), the file could be not a valid image.

Comment: Can you see my updated question? I've added the image generation methods

Comment: Are you creating an image from randomly generated bytes? Does it work on windows?

Answer (score 4):

While not specified by the OP, if you are using .NET 6, `System.Drawing.Common` is only supported on Linux via a backwards compatibility runtime config setting.  **It is completely deprecated in .NET 7.**

From MSDN:

> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the following libraries:
>
> - [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp)
> - [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
> - [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](https://github.com/dotnet/Microsoft.Maui.Graphics)
>
> Alternatively, you can enable support for non-Windows platforms in .NET 6 by setting the `System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport` [runtime configuration switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/) to `true` in the `runtimeconfig.json` (`runtimeconfig.template.json`) file:

```
{
   "configProperties": {
      "System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport": true
   }
}
```

This configuration switch was added to give cross-platform apps that depend heavily on this package time to migrate to more modern libraries. However, non-Windows bugs will not be fixed. In addition, this switch has been removed in .NET 7.

See here for more info - [System.Drawing.Common only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only)

Comment: Thank you for being my tour guide today! :)  It does amaze me though that MSFT would rely on third party packages for something as basic as Image class.  The Maui Graphics repos says it's 'experimental' and was archived last month.